# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (When init)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have below error in latest Xcode8 when build project.

1. While emitting IR SIL function

> @_TFC10Test_UAT15IOS_CNXResponsecfT6nsdataGSqV10Foundation4Data_10nsresponseGSqCSo11URLResponse_7nserrorGSqCSo7NSError__S0_ for 'init' at /Users/test/Desktop/Test/AsyncRequest.swift:255:5

Below is my 255 line code. I don't know which part causing this error. Please advice.

```
  init(nsdata:Data?, nsresponse:URLResponse?, nserror:NSError?) {

        data = nsdata!
        response = nsresponse!
        error = nserror
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `super.init()` from inside your init() method (you will need to pass in any relevant parameters too).